# Building a power strip from scratch

Tags: power

I'm considering building my own power strip for multiple different reasons.

I've been trying to research these, but haven't found much information.

I obviously know what makes up a power strip, but I'm wondering if the copper(?) rails within the strip housing are something you can buy premade and then build the housing myself? If so, what would these rails be called?

Thanks!

Comment: what are `multiple different reasons`?

Comment: Power strips/multi-plug are common and relatively cheap. Hence making your own would cost more than just buying one. In addition, a power strip carries mains voltage, which will be fatal if you don't take into account in your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't make outlets from scratch like that. You must use UL-approved outlets from the hardware store; otherwise, your insurance company could deny your claim when your house burns down.

Comment: Great, thanks! Did not think about that

Comment: A lot of assumptions going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Generally those rails are called "sections of house wiring with the insulation stripped off".

And yes, what Dave said about DIY and UL -- but I still use the power strip I made for myself in the electronics prototyping shop at Worcester Polytechnic Institute 30 years ago.